# How to solve EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a Unity app?

Tags: c#, c++, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

My Unity game works fine in Unity Editor.

I wanted to test it on my iPhone so I built the app and loaded it in my iPhone via Xcode. Problem is the app seems to be stuck in a loop.

After multiple searches I learned that using the Simulator gives me more info on the problem so I did use it and it returns this:

> Job.Worker 10 (31): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x133ac1000)

After more searches I've found a way to get more infos:

> **thread #31, name = 'Job.Worker 10', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x133ac1000)**
> **frame #0:** 0x00007ff836167049 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell + 41
> **frame #1:** 0x00007ff82e58865d MTLSimDriver`+[MTLSimTexture decompress:expandedTex:srcFormat:destFormat:width:height:destRowBytes:srcRowBytes:] + 209
> **frame #2:** 0x00007ff82e58ad3f MTLSimDriver`-[MTLSimTexture replaceRegion:mipmapLevel:slice:withBytes:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:] + 801
> **frame #3:** 0x0000000119112ca7 libiPhone-lib.dylib``UploadTextureData(TextureCreateDataMetal&) ``` + 986   **frame #4:** 0x0000000117f134d0 libiPhone-lib.dylib\``CopyToTextureMemory2DThreaded(TextureCreateData*, TextureUploadMemory&) ``` + 53
> **frame #5:** 0x0000000117ec94b0 libiPhone-lib.dylib``DoCopyTextureDataJob(TextureUploadInstruction*) ``` + 60   **frame #6:** 0x0000000117fc7af2 libiPhone-lib.dylib\``JobQueue::Exec(JobInfo*, long long, int, bool) ``` + 100
> **frame #7:** 0x0000000117fc7e0b libiPhone-lib.dylib``JobQueue::Steal(JobGroup*, JobInfo*, long long, int, bool, bool) ``` + 359   **frame #8:** 0x0000000117fc7fe7 libiPhone-lib.dylib\``JobQueue::ExecuteJobFromQueue(bool, bool&) ``` + 221
> **frame #9:** 0x0000000117fc8243 libiPhone-lib.dylib``JobQueue::ProcessJobs(JobQueue::ThreadInfo*, void*) ``` + 387   **frame #10:** 0x0000000117fc7302 libiPhone-lib.dylib\``JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) ``` + 286
> **frame #11:** 0x00000001183768cc libiPhone-lib.dylib``Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) `+ 686   **frame #12:** 0x00007ff836176259 libsystem_pthread.dylib\`_pthread_start + 125
> **frame #13:** 0x00007ff836171c7b libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 15

But.. It's mostly gibberish to me..

### Context

When my scene loads, my Unity game executes a Firebase Function to get all the characters created by the current player/user. While waiting for the function to run and get data from the server, I display a loading animation.
After getting the data, I display a "card" for each character found. A card contains the name and the level of the character.
After every cards have been initialized and populated with correct data, I disable the loading animation and the scene is finally ready.
Now the user can select a card corresponding to a character and it will update the character 3D model visible in the scene with corresponding character appearance.

### Problem

When generating the cards, I pre-select the first character's card. This action involves updating the character preview (character 3D model).
The error in Xcode is thrown as soon as I try to access the character according to my `Debug.Log()s`.
At the beginning of the scene, before it tries to execute the function, Xcode says:

> Unloading 5 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
> UnloadTime: 1.856800 ms
> Unloading 68 unused Assets / (50.2 KB). Loaded Objects now: 1057.

The character is always present in the scene and I never get rid of it. If the player has no character returned by the Cloud Function, the character (3D model) will just be hidden (`gameObject.SetActive(false)` in Unity C#) but is still there.
With this, plus the mention of "texture" in the error thrown and the fact that it is thrown when my code tries to access the Character object, they all seem related but what can I do?

It's been two weeks already I couldn't gather more info than this.. I hope this is enough for you to help me because I'm absolutely out of idea to solve this and why my character wouldn't exist anymore if I don't code it to do so.

*More infos:*
Unity version: **2021.3.17f1**
macOS version: **Ventura 13.1**
Xcode version: **14.2**
iOS version (my iPhone and Simulator): **16.2**

Comment: Unfortunately, this is far, far short of being "enough" for anyone to be able to help you, I'm afraid. The only realistic way to determine the root cause of the crashes is to use a debugger in order to determine the root cause for the crash. Without having complete access to the source code, and the crashing application, the only thing that anyone can possibly tell you are random guesses.

Comment: As @SamVarshavchik, without code, it's going to be difficult to help you, but try to understand that EXC_BAD_ACCESS is caused because you are trying to access an object that has already been released from memory. If you are unable to share code, try to look at this problem as a memory management issue. Do you think your character object is released somewhere before it is accessed? Or perhaps the object that contains the character object is released prior to the access.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to access the character object in a closure where you haven't captured the object.. And like Sam said, all of these are just guesses

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Skywalker and @Sam Varshavchik, your comments helped a lot in fact!

I'll give details if it can help anyone in the future:

I tried really hard trying to get more info before editing my question and add tons of code and explanation after reading your comments.

My character object in my scene looks like this:

```
Player / PlayerIdentity.cs + others
 |_ Model / PlayerModelManager.cs
```

**`Player`** gameobject contains all the Player's scripts (identity, movement, inventory etc.), and **`Model`** gameobject contains the actual 3D model (skinned mesh renderers) and a script (`PlayerModelManager.cs`) to manage it (change hairstyle, gender, change hair color etc..)

When selecting a card in my scene, it goes like this (simplified):
`MyScene.UpdateCharacterPreview()` > `PlayerModelManager.SwitchGender()` > `PlayerIdentity.SetGender()`.

Instead of pre-selecting the first character (in Scene `Start()` method) I want to display on screen, I commented this code and decided to observe how it would behave if I "manually" trigger this code by selecting myself a character's card to show the character preview.
Fortunately, it showed a new error in Xcode -> the infamous `NullReferenceException` for `PlayerIdentity.cs` reference in my `PlayerModelManager.cs` script.

But I didn't understand because in Unity it is not `null`, the reference is there as it should be. So I did some research and stumbled upon [this](https://2dtoolkit.com/forum/index.php?topic=1495.0). Especially the last post.

In my scene, I disable in the `Awake()` method the whole **Model** gameobject (and therefore `PlayerModelManager.cs`) to hide the character while getting data from server. If the player has no character returned by the server, the model stays hidden.
Code used to hide the model is `playerModelGameObject.SetActive(false)`.

The `PlayerModelManager.cs` gets its reference to `PlayerIdentity.cs` in its `Awake()` method.
My assumption is : by disabling the player model in my scene `Awake()` method, `PlayerModelManager.cs` doesn't have time to get its reference to `PlayerIdentity.cs` in its own `Awake()` method.

So instead, I disabled the player model in my scene `Start()` method, so the
`PlayerModelManager.cs`'s `Awake()` method can be executed entirely and get necessary references.

I don't really know why it only happens on iOS builds but now it is solved at least.
If anyone has the knowledge to know why, I would be very interested.

Thanks